# Reverse Uptime Monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, monitoring, upstart

There are plenty of tools out there to check your website uptime. I'm looking for a tool that does the opposite...that is I send a 3rd party a message once a minute and it alerts me if it misses one.

My problem is I have a long running process that randomly hung one day. I wasn't able to get to the bottom of it and it hasn't happened since but I want to monitor it. I'm using upstart on Ubuntu to monitor the process and restart it if it crashes...the problem is it didn't crash just hanged.

Comment: You could use Icinca/Nagios *passive checks* in combination with *check freshness* to get that behavior. Or simply `touch` a file every time a message gets through, and have another process monitor that file and alert if it is older than some threshold.

Comment: What do you mean by 3rd party? Who's that third party, what kind of messages do you want to send, etc? :)

Comment: @favoretti something like pingdom or new relic. I just want to send a "I'm alive" message once a minute and for the 3rd party to alert me if it doesn't receive one in 2 minutes.

Comment: Hmm, something like a cron script that does it won't do? You want some "solution" for that? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the reverse uptime monitoring service, https://deadmanssnitch.com is one.

As a recommendation for efficiently monitoring processes, try one of these:

- [Cognizant](https://github.com/Gurpartap/cognizant)
- [God](http://godrb.com)
- [Bluepill](https://github.com/arya/bluepill)
- [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org)
- [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)